How to encrypt my key when persisting it to my AWS management secrets?
I stored in my AWS Management Secrets my secret key to my JWT Token that i'm using for the Log in of my app.
Also , i'm connecting to an IAM account where i can retrieve my secret key for the JWT token generation.
The problem is , that when i run my web API program , after i succesfully retrieved the key from the vault, the application runs , but i get this warning.
info: AWSSDK[0]
      Found AWS credentials for the profile RiderConnection
info: Amazon.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SSM.SSMXmlRepository[0]
      Using SSM Parameter Store to persist DataProtection keys with parameter name prefix /prod/texx.ro/JWT_Key/
info: Amazon.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SSM.SSMXmlRepository[0]
      Loaded 0 DataProtection keys
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {6b10e676-e1c7-42c5-9270-d826fe3b04a6} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Amazon.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SSM.SSMXmlRepository[0]
      Using SSM parameter tier Standard for DataProtection element /prod/texx.ro/JWT_Key/key-6b10e676-e1c7-42c5-9270-d826fe3b04a6
info: Amazon.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SSM.SSMXmlRepository[0]
      Saved DataProtection key to SSM Parameter Store with parameter name /prod/texx.ro/JWT_Key/key-6b10e676-e1c7-42c5-9270-d826fe3b04a6

I'm currently running .NET 8 .
This is my setup in Program.cs
var region = builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions();
AWSOptions awsOptions = new AWSOptions
{
    Profile = "RiderConnection",
    ProfilesLocation = "/Users/misustefan/.aws/credentials",
    Region = region.Region
};
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(awsOptions);


// Add AWS services
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAmazonSecretsManager>(sp =>
{
    var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(awsOptions.Credentials,awsOptions.Region);
    return client;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAmazonKeyManagementService>(sp =>
{
    var client = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(awsOptions.Credentials,awsOptions.Region);
    return client;
});

// Add data protection 
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToAWSSystemsManager("prod/texx.ro/JWT_Key")

/* rest of code */

I even asked the GPT , but i could not understand , or i did now know how to ask him . I understand that It asks for an encryption . Is there a way where i do not have to write another class that encrypts/decrypts my key and just to install a package and use an encryption already generated by the AWS ? ( I installed some , but the tutorials are old and are not applicable anymore). I just started working with aws , this is like my second day . Try to explain like you would to a 10 year old , I am still learning . Thank you!

Where are you using these AWS credentials?  In EC2 or on your own device outside of AWS?
